# Выровнять элементы в WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms

Добавил на форму два элемента:

```
bindingNavigator1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

Почему при таких настройках заголовки таблицы уходят за элемент bindingNavigator1?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы форма выглядела вот так и при этом нормально масштабировалась?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы получили такой стиль самого окна, DevExpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-кликните по Binding Navigator в дизайнере и выберите "Send to Back".

Или используете `TableLayout` с двумя строками с включенным `AutoSize`.

Или вручную выровняйте грид в дизайнере (без установки `Dock.Fill`), и задайте у него свойство `Anchor` = `Bottom|Left|Right` - тогда он будет расширятся при изменении размеров формы.